# New c++ project at visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have been working with eclipse for c++ and all was fine. I want to try visual studio.

I have opened new project:

myTree.h:

```
#ifndef myTree_H_
#define myTree_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>


class Node {
    std::string word;

public:
    Node() {
        word="TEST";
    }
    std::string getString() {
        return word;
    }
}

#endif /* myTree_H_ */
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "myTree.h"

int main() {
    Node myNode;

    std::cout << myNode.getString() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but I have build errors:

```
c++\tree2\test.cpp(6): error C2628: 'Node' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
c++\tree2\test.cpp(6): error C3874: return type of 'main' should be 'int' instead of 'Node'
 c++\tree2\test.cpp(11): error C2664: 'Node::Node(const Node &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'const Node &'
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const Node'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I cant understand why is that.. anyone can help?

Comment: Add a `;` to the end of your class definition.

Comment: How do you terminate a class definition? A closing brace `}` *and* a...?

Comment: Look a bit more close at what the error message actually says: `(did you forget a ';'?)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joachim's answer (in comments):

You forgot to add a `;` after you class definition. The compiler suggests it too.